# Array compare and count which has similar values and which not

Tags: php, arrays

I have situation that I have to compare dynamic arrays, and get count of arrays with similar values for first four keys only. For ex:

```
Array[0]
(
    [item] => 1
    [size] => 1
    [pair] => 1
    [pay] => 1
    [name] => 
    [msg] => 
    [email] => 
    [b19e19b13682bcfef93651c86f9ad9e6] => eih6j74035oj17bvnses32km23
)
Array[1]
(
    [item] => 1
    [size] => 2
    [pair] => 1
    [pay] => 1
    [name] => 
    [msg] => 
    [email] => 
    [b19e19b13682bcfef93651c86f9ad9e6] => eih6j74035oj17bvnses32km23
)
Array[2]
(
    [item] => 1
    [size] => 2
    [pair] => 2
    [pay] => 2
    [name] => 
    [msg] => 
    [email] => 
    [b19e19b13682bcfef93651c86f9ad9e6] => eih6j74035oj17bvnses32km23
)
Array[3]
(
    [item] => 1
    [size] => 1
    [pair] => 1
    [pay] => 1
    [name] => 
    [msg] => 
    [email] => 
    [b19e19b13682bcfef93651c86f9ad9e6] => eih6j74035oj17bvnses32km23
)
```

I have the above set of arrays which has 1st and last iterations has similar values(for 1st four keys). For this I have to derive something like (0,3),(1),(2). is there any solution for this?

Comment: have you tried anything? Did you google first?

Comment: you have 4 fix records or it may very as per your code ?

Comment: Yes. I tried with if condition but it comes around 30 combinations. But it may increase if one more key is added. Googled it as well, but got no solutions.

Comment: Possible duplication with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574890/compare-array-values-with-others-values-from-the-same-array/33781903#33781903

Comment: Can you define *similar values*? Like exactly the same or what do you mean with this?

Comment: Combine the values of the keys you use for comparison into a single value using the appropriate separator (the values seem to be numbers, you can use dash or comma or a letter or some other non-digit character). Copy the items you need into a new array, use the newly generated value as key to identify the new entries created from "similar values".

Answer (score 0):

this should works fine:

put your arrays in one array as I did in `$arrays`, then:

```
<?php
$arrays = [
array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4),
array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4),
array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4),
array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>4, 'd'=>3),
];

$result = [];

//get the keys of a sub-array that is inside $arrays, to be used later
$keys = array_keys($arrays[0]);

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arrays); $i++){

    $sa = array(); // to store similar arrays indexes

    for($k=$i+1; $k < sizeof($arrays); $k++){

        $similar = false;

        //compare the values of keys in the two arrays. Just compare the first 4 keys (as the user's desire)
        for($j=0; $j < 4; $j++){

            //check if the values are similar, if they are, assign $similar to true, and assign $j=3 to end the loop, (a bit of laziness here)
            ($similar = $arrays[$i][$keys[$j]] == $arrays[$k][$keys[$j]] ? true : false) ? null : ($j=3); 
        }

        // check if the key (which represents an index in $arrays) is in $sa or not, if not, push it.
        $similar ? (in_array($i, $sa) ? null : array_push($sa, $i) && in_array($k, $sa) ? null : array_push($sa, $k)) : null;
        //if $similar is true, make $i jumps to the $k index (saving time)
        $similar ? $i=$k : null;
    }

    //if $sa not empty, push it to $result
    empty($sa) ? null : ($result[] = $sa);
}

/* 
// at this stage, $result includes all the similar arrays
// so we need another loop to push the unique arrays to $result
// just check if an index of $arrays is in an sub-array of $result, if not, push it as an array of one record 
*/

for($j=0; $j < sizeof($arrays); $j++){
    $f = false;
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++){
        in_array($j, $result[$i]) ? $f = true : null;
    }
    if(!$f){
        $sa = array();
        array_push($sa, $j);
        array_push($result, $sa);
    }
}
```

finally, $result is an array of arrays, each sub-array values represents an index of $arrays
if the result output is :

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
            [1]=> int(1) 
            [2]=> int(2) 
    },
    [1]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(3) 
    } 
}
```

this means that $arrays has two groups of sub-arrays, 
where $arrays[0], $arrays[1], and $arrays[2] are similar (group 1), then $arrays[3] is unique (group 2)

**N.B**: I would appreciate if anyone could optimize my answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Mohammad, the `result` output is `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
  }
}`. Could you explain it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest each array in `$result` represents a group of similar arrays, where the values are the indexes of `$arrays`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i prefer OOP approach : more clean, reusable...

**USAGE**

```
$o = new SOF_ArrayComapare($yourInputArray, array('item', 'size', 'pair', 'pay', 'name'));
$arraysEqual = $o->getEqualArrays();
print $o->toString();
```

**CLASS DEFINITION**

```
class SOF_ArrayComapare {
    private $_keysToMatch   = array();
    private $_array         = array();

    public function __construct($array, $keysToMatch) {
        $this->_array       = $array;
        $this->_keysToMatch = $keysToMatch;
    }

    private $_equalArrays   = array();
    private $_indexToEscape = array();

    public function getEqualArrays() {
        $size = count($this->_array);
        for ($i=0 ; $i<$size ; $i++) {

            if (in_array($i, $this->_indexToEscape))    continue;
            else                                        $this->_indexToEscape[] = $i;

            $this->_equalArrays[$i][] = $i;
            for ($j=($i+1) ; $j<$size ; $j++) {
                if (in_array($j, $this->_indexToEscape)) continue;
                if ($this->areEquals($this->_array[$i], $this->_array[$j])) {
                    $this->_indexToEscape[]     = $j;
                    $this->_equalArrays[$i][]   = $j;
                }
            }   
        }
        return $this->_equalArrays;
    }

    private function areEquals($a1, $a2) {
        foreach($this->_keysToMatch as $key) {
            if(
                !isset($a1[$key]) || 
                !isset($a2[$key]) ||
                $a1[$key] !== $a2[$key]
            ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function toString($htmlFormat = TRUE) {
        $newLine = ($htmlFormat === TRUE) ? '<br />' : "\n";
        $report = "These arrays are equals: " . $newLine;
        foreach($this->_equalArrays as $array) {
            $report .= '(' . implode(',', $array) . ')' . $newLine;
        }
        return $report;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain this at the end, but the code is pretty self explanatory:

```
function getDuplicatesArray()
{
    $foundIndexes = array();
    $arraysCount = count(Array);
    $resultArray = array();
    // $i is current index
    // $j is compared index
    for ($i = 0; i < $arraysCount; i++)
    {
        if (in_array($i, $foundIndexes))
            continue;

        $currentResultArray = array($i);

        for ($j = $i+1; $j<$arraysCount; $j++)
        {
            if (in_array($j, $foundIndexes))
                continue;
            if(areFirstValsSame($i,$j))
            {   
                $currentResultArray[] = $j;
                if (count($currentResultArray) == 2) // first j for this i
                    foundIndexes[] = $i;
                foundIndexes[] = $j;
            }       
        }
        $resultArray[] = $currentResultArray;
    }//.. for i
}//.. getDuplicatesArray

function areFirstValsSame($index1, $index2){
    $toCompare = 4;
    for ($i=0; i<$toCompare; i++)
        if (Array($index1, i) != Array($index2, i)
            return false;
    return true; 
}
```

A "found" array saves all indexes with duplicates.

When a duplicate is found the Array's index is added to the "found".

A current-found saves all indexes of duplicate Arrays being compared to the current Array.

Then before testing the next index, check if it was found before, and if so skip it.

Once an index has been compared (whether finding a duplicate or not) its current-found is added to the result.

If all four Arrays were the same you would get: `(0,1,2,3)` and if the first and third were duplicate and the second and fourth you would get: (0,2),(1,3) etc.

You would not be checking a duplicate twice. But you would still need to re-read the values of those Arrays that were not found duplicate to the indices checked till now.

That could be optimized by recursion, but would take up more memory, and with this small amount of arrays, it would not even be noticeable.